# Javascript Commands to PHP

Tags: php, xml

What would be the equivalent of this javascript to PHP? I want to traspose this javascript code to php...Im mostly interested in this :

1. -getElementsByTagName
2. -document.write("")
3. -create a document with "variable" as filename.

Here's some of the code:

```
document.write("<table border='1'>");
  var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title");
  for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<tr><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("artist")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr>");
 }
document.write("</table>");
```

Thanks you for your time!

Comment: You probably want to [learn xslt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php).

Comment: You want to rewrite rendering this part of page to PHP?

Comment: I don't think this would be easy, since PHP works on server side, and JavaScript works on client side. Just leave the work of each language to what is created for.

Comment: It's not clear what is the purpose of transpose this code.

Comment: I don't see why it should be clear, but I've changed the question completely.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer I've added 'clarity' to my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look into [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). From there I'd use [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) to query the data I want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I gave it a read and changed my mind completely on the focus of my question.